# Convert struct column to Scala list

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a struct column in my dataframe and I want to collect it as a Scala list.

```
case class Class1(x1: Integer, x2: Double)

val df = Seq(("a", Class1(10,5.5)), ("b", Class1(7,2.1))).toDF("id", "col1")
```

When I try to convert the struct column to an `RDD` and collect it:

```
df.select($"col1").rdd.map(x => x.asInstanceOf[Array[(Integer, Double)]]).collect()
```

I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema cannot be cast to [Lscala.Tuple2;
```

I want to return

```
List((10,5.5),(7,2.1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have a `case class` you can take advantage of it when collecting the data. Simply convert the `DataFrame` to a `DataSet[Class1]` before using `collect`. This will give you the list you want:

```
df.select($"col1.*").as[Class1].collect().toList
```

Comment: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`x1`' given input columns: [col1];

Comment: @JohnWaller: Fixed, thanks for pointing it out. There was a typo in the answer, it should be `select($"col1.*")` and not `select($"col1")`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.` notation to select the `struct` column to separate columns and use that column names to turn that to `tuple` in `map` function of `rdd` and you should get your desired output.

```
df.select($"col1.*").rdd.map(x=> (x.getAs[Integer]("x1"), x.getAs[Double]("x2"))).collect.toList
//List((10,5.5), (7,2.1))
```

I hope the answer is helpful